# Python/Flask Method Not Allowed error, but only when running program via shell script

Tags: python, flask

I am aware the "Method Not Allowed" question has appeared several times here, but I believe my situation is unique, and I cannot find any questions/solutions that seems to apply to me.

I have a python program running on a hardware server running Red Hat Linux v6.3. Normally this program is run using a shell script that runs on boot in the /etc/init.d directory.

When run via the shell script (as it is supposed to be run), one of my routes fails to send information from an HTML form to the Python backend. Giving a HTTP 500 Error, and if I try and go to address of the route in question, I get the "Method Not Allowed".

However, when trying to debug the program, I ssh into the server, and run the program using

```
python ts480webserver.py
```

And the program works fine. No HTTP 500 Error, No "Method Not Allowed" Error. Data is sent to the back end and received again, all working great.

Any ideas as to what could cause there to be a problem with Flask accessing the python /applynewsettings route ONLY when run by the shell script, and not when run directly?

Some Code Below

**Shell Script**

```
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

RETVAL=0
PIDFILE=/var/run/ts480webserver.pid

prog=ts480webserver.py
exec=/srv/www/htdocs/$prog
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog

# Source config
if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/$prog ] ; then
    . /etc/sysconfig/$prog
fi


start() {
    [ -x $exec ] || exit 5
    logger -t TS480 "TS480 web server boot up"
    echo -n $"Starting TS480 Web Server: "
    daemon --pidfile="$PIDFILE" "$exec -i $PIDFILE </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
}
```

**Python**

```
@app.route("/applynewsettings", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def apply_new_settings():

    # TAKES IN JSON with user input data from front end
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sys_settings = request.json

    # PARSES it to get important info (not shown)

    # SEND CMD (string based on user input) to CLI via Telnet
    cli.sendCmd(sia_cmd)

    # RETURN string reporting any validation errors that occured to show to front end
    return sia_err_msg
```

**Javascript**

```
apply_settings_config_accordion = function(callback){
  mtu = $("#MTU-dropdown option:selected").text()
  interface_selected = $("#interface-dropdown option:selected").text()
  ip_address = $("#sysconfig-ip-address-input").val();
  subnet_mask = $("#sysconfig-subnet-input").val();
  gateway = $("#sysconfig-gateway-input").val();

  settings = {"mtu": mtu, "ip_address": ip_address, "subnet_mask": subnet_mask, "gateway": gateway, "interface": interface_selected}
  console.log("settings: \t"+JSON.stringify(settings));

  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: "/applynewsettings",
      data: JSON.stringify(settings)
  })
  .done(function(sysconfig_err_msg){
    sysconfig_err_msg = sysconfig_err_msg.replace(/\n/g, "<br>" ) //String.fromCharCode(13)
    $("#static-ip-input-err").html(sysconfig_err_msg);

    setTimeout(function(){ load_settings_config(); }, 1000);

  });
};
```

Comment: This is a little wierd IMO...have you looked through your logs? and the traceback?. also you can fire up `pdb` in the body of the route and inspect the `request` object (it's type, the incoming data if there's any etc) That might give you a clue on what's happening.

Comment: Nothing in the logs. There is no traceback info because I can only get that info when running it directly (python file.py), and doing that causes the error not to happen. I've never used pdb but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds exactly like a problem I have seen before.

The code you have included may not suggest it, but check and make sure that if any routes have you opening files for reading/writing that the paths can be resolved regardless of whether you run it from the working directory or from the shell script.

I am sure running your Flask app through the shell script with debug set to "True" will quickly expose the cause of your 500 error, whatever it may be.  Just make sure to set it back to "False" afterwards.